# How to write in English for international readers?

Tags: writing, writing-style, international

**How to write in English for international readers?**

I'm not a native English speaker but I've been learning the language for many years in many fields (Mathematics, Physics, Mechanical Engineering and Programming to name some). Every now and then I find something explained in 'basic' English that I just cannot figure out without some search. Along the way I learned some small tricks for writing English for foreigners.

Assume that the reader has an **intermediate-high English level** to answer this. The **reading fluency** is the main concern in this question, not the learning of the reader. I also wanted to give my 2 cents in this so I'll answer my own question in community wiki format, so please **add your advice** there.

This question came up to me after reading the word 'Jeopardy!' in [this stack overflow blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

EDIT: I read this afterwards (which seems pretty mistaken):

> John Saunders: I wonder what proportion of StackExchange users don’t know what “Jeopardy” is?
>
> Jeff Atwood (author): @john I suppose the same proportion that don’t know what “Wikipedia” and “Clicking a Link” is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Make your English readable internationally.

After some investigation myself, I found [this](http://messagecom.wordpress.com/2009/02/03/how-to-write-english-for-international-readers/) and [this](http://www.webpagecontent.com/arc_archive/139/5/) great articles, which I'll use to complete what I already learned. Note that, since this is for intermediate-high level foreign speakers, I omit some of the advise in these articles (they understand perfectly 'It is...').

### Use short sentences.

Relatively short sentences are easier to digest and understand. Furthermore, they are also easier to translate by automated translators. A 5 lines sentence is difficult to read even for most native speakers.

### Don't use anything that is on the TV

This includes mainly TV programs (as Jeopardy!), celebrities and jokes. How would a Spanish reader know what is the meaning of "Legen...Wait For It...Dary" when they have it translated and it's not even so popular there. Although if you must talk about them...

### Include visual content!

Many TV programs have similar ones in every country (for Jeopardy, [Saber y Ganar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saber_y_Ganar) in Spain), so they might recognize easily what you're talking about if you include a picture. For celebrities, they might have seen the celebrity before somewhere in a movie, show or online, so a photo will help greatly. Anyhow, pictures and visual content is [widely advised for writing online](http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/33423/19-Reasons-You-Should-Include-Visual-Content-in-Your-Marketing-Data.aspx).

### Write in the same way 30-50 years old people do.

The [average age of teachers](http://nces.ed.gov/pubs2009/2009324/tables/sass0708_2009324_t12n_03.asp) is that one. Foreigners are taught normally by teachers. So the English they're being taught is the one that 30-50 years old people speak. Furthermore, these teachers learned English when they were younger from other 30-50 yo teachers (only reinforcing my point).

### Urban Dictionary is evil

If its meaning is only in [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/), you better don't use it. If you must use it, include some link to the meaning or a small quote of it. Foreign students normally speak in their language, so no new jokes are learned about the English language.

---

Please, consider adding more or improving the ones added.